# UISwitch - How do I not make it animate

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I have a UISwitch that shows the password when it's ON and hides it when it's OFF. When it's clicked, an AlertView pops up asking for a password then confirm. My problem is the switch still switches to display the OFF text instead of it still being ON when the user clicks on it/enters the wrong password. I need it to still read the ON status/text until the user successfully enters the correct password on the alertview.

Comment: Something like: `setOn:animated:`?

Comment: Do u mean that the user can't make it off until he enters a password in the alert?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the switch moves to the OFF text, I need it to still display the ON text when the user clicks it until he types in the correct password and then the switch displays the OFF text and the password is visible. It's for security purposes of the app i'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 
in your interface do this

```
IBOutlet UISwitch *passwordSwitch;
```

Step 2
set your switch to the above

Step 3
Upon your logic if the password fails do this

```
    passwordSwitch.on=NO;
```

Edit:

If it succeed do this

```
    passwordSwitch.on=YES;
```

Comment: Thanks alot! it did solve the displayed text but it still switches to OFF when I click on it and after I enter the wrong pass, it goes back to ON. Is there any way to stop it from animating to OFF after I click it?

Comment: Ok I guess I could live with that. THANKS ALOT!!